# How to escape a character in a variable?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a script that passes a variable into a sed command like this:

```
sed "s-\t-&${SUBDIRECTORY}/-"
```

But if the variable contains `-` (dash), then the sed command throws an error.

So this script:

```
VARIABLE="test-variable"
sed "s-\t-&${VARIABLE}/-"
```

Results in this error:

```
sed: 1: "s-\t-&test-variable/-": bad flag in substitute command: 'v'
```

I have not been able to find any answers to this issue; it works fine without the `-`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you use `-` as a regex delimiter escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell parameter expansion that escapes each instance of `-`:

```sh
sed "s-\t-&${VARIABLE//-/\\-}/-"
```

In the Bash manual, under [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. [...] If *pattern* begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*. Normally only the first match is replaced. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Proper escaping is a fairly difficult problem in the shell, but you could do something like:

```
$ variable="test-variable"
$ printf '\t\n' | v="$variable" perl -pe 's-\t-$ENV{v}-'
test-variable
```